# Randomly Shuffle Rows Based on a Column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with 8 columns and about 300 rows. One of the columns ("D") is labeled "Grouped" which has either a "Yes" or "No" value. "Grouped" rows, i.e., those rows with a "Yes" value on the "Grouped" column, usually are composed of 2-5 rows, and appears in between the "No" rows. Using VBA, I wish to shuffle the order of rows starting from Row 2 up to the last used Row but following these conditions:

1. Grouped rows cannot be shuffled.
2. The position of Grouped rows may change, e.g. Grouped rows at Row 50-53 can be moved to Row 1-4, and Grouped rows Row 100-103 can be moved to Row 150-153.

Before:
[image: Before sort]

After:
[image: After sort]

I tried assigning a random value to a row in a new column and apply a sort based on that new column, but I cannot meet the conditions. I've tried row swapping using selections, i.e., "filtered out" the Grouped rows, but they still end up being shuffled.

Comment: I did a similar thing with groups of 5 questions for a 5 question quiz. Each question came from a random selection of one of the 5 questions in a group. No sorting of the groups required as the choice was made by a random number between 1 and 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This macro should work for you:

```
<code>Sub Shuffle()
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim AR1() As Variant
Dim AR2() As Variant
Dim R1 As Range
Dim Num As Long
Dim AA As Integer
Dim BB As Long
Dim CC As Integer
Dim DD As Integer
Lrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A200000").End(xlUp).Row
Set R1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:H" & Lrow)
ReDim AR1(1 To (Lrow - 1), 1 To 8)
ReDim AR2(1 To (Lrow - 1), 1 To 8)
AR1 = R1
For BB = LBound(AR1, 1) To UBound(AR1, 1)
    AA = 1
    If AR1(BB, 3) = "Yes" Then
        Num = BB
        Do Until Num = 0
            Num = Num + 1
            If Num > UBound(AR1, 1) Then
                Num = 0
            Else
                If AR1(Num, 3) = "No" Then
                    Num = 0
                Else
                    AA = AA + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        Do Until Num <> 0
            Num = Int((UBound(AR1, 1) - LBound(AR1, 1) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(AR1, 1))
            For CC = 1 To AA
                If (Num + CC - 1) > UBound(AR1, 1) Then
                    Num = 0
                    Exit For
                Else
                    If AR2(Num + CC - 1, 3) <> "" Then
                        Num = 0
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next CC
        Loop
        For CC = 1 To AA
            For DD = 1 To 8
                AR2(Num + CC - 1, DD) = AR1(BB + CC - 1, DD)
            Next DD
            AR1(BB + CC - 1, 3) = ""
        Next CC
    End If
Next BB
For BB = LBound(AR1, 1) To UBound(AR1, 1)
    If AR1(BB, 3) <> "" Then
        AA = 0
        Num = 0
        Do Until Num <> 0
            Num = Int((UBound(AR1, 1) - LBound(AR1, 1) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(AR1, 1))
            If AR2(Num, 3) = "" Then
                For DD = 1 To 8
                    AR2(Num, DD) = AR1(BB, DD)
                Next DD
                AR1(BB, 3) = ""
            Else
                Num = 0
                AA = AA + 1
            End If
            If AA > 10 Then
                For CC = LBound(AR1, 1) To UBound(AR1, 1)
                    If AR2(CC, 3) = "" Then
                        For DD = 1 To 8
                            AR2(CC, DD) = AR1(BB, DD)
                        Next DD
                        AR1(BB, 3) = ""
                        Num = CC
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next CC
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next BB
R1 = AR2
End Sub
</code>
```

good luck

Comment: This is amazing, @spiralrain! It DID do what I needed, ticking all of the boxes. THANK YOU! I am studying the code now and applying some minor edits to make it more flexible for other applications.